# Units of perf stat statistics

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, perf

I'm using perf stat for some purposes and to better understand the working of the tool , I wrote a program that copies a file's contents into another . I ran the program on a 750MB file and the stats are below

```
   31691336329 L1-dcache-loads                                             
      44227451 L1-dcache-load-misses       
   15596746809 L1-dcache-stores                                            
      20575093 L1-dcache-store-misses                                      
      26542169 cache-references                                            
      13410669 cache-misses                 
   36859313200 cycles                            
   75952288765 instructions                      
      26542163 cache-references
```

what is the units of each number . what I mean is . Is it bits/bytes/ or something else . Thanks in advance.

Comment: They have no unit. The numbers show how many times an event happened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The unit is "single cache access" for loads, stores, references and misses. Loads correspond to count of load instructions, executed by processors; same for stores. Misses is the count, how much loads and stores were unable to get their data loaded from the cache of this level: L1 data cache for `L1-dcache-` events; Last Level Cache (usually L2 or L3 depending on your platform) for `cache-` events.

```
31 691 336 329 L1-dcache-loads                                             
    44 227 451 L1-dcache-load-misses       
15 596 746 809 L1-dcache-stores                                            
    20 575 093 L1-dcache-store-misses                                      


    26 542 169 cache-references                                            
    13 410 669 cache-misses
```

Cycles is the total count of CPU ticks, for which CPU executed your program. If you have 3 GHz CPU, there will be around 3 000 000 000 cycles per second at most. If the machine was busy, there will be less cycles available for your program

```
36 859 313 200 cycles
```

This is total count of instructions, executed from your program:

```
75 952 288 765 instructions
```

(I will use G suffix as abbreviation for billion)

From the numbers we can conclude: 76G instructions executed in 37G cycles (around 2 instructions per cpu tick, rather high level of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle)). You gave no information of your CPU and its frequency, but assuming 3 GHz CPU, the running time was near 12 seconds.

In 76G instructions, you have 31G load instructions (42%), and 15G store instructions (21%); so only 37% of instructions were no memory instructions. I don't know, what was the size of memory references (was it byte load and stores, 2 byte or wide SSE movs), but 31G load instructions looks too high for 750 MB file (mean is 0.02 bytes; but shortest possible load and store is single byte). So I think that your program did several copies of the data; or the file was bigger. 750 MB in 12 seconds looks rather slow (60 MBytes/s), but this can be true, if the first file was read and second file was written to the disk, without caching by Linux kernel (do you have `fsync()` call in your program? Do you profile your CPU or your HDD?). With cached files and/or RAMdrive (tmpfs - the filesystem, stored in the RAM memory) this speed should be much higher.

Modern versions of perf does some simple calculations in `perf stat` and also may print units, like shown here: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/hpc-prof-events.html

```
perf stat -d  md5sum *

    578.920753 task-clock                #    0.995 CPUs utilized
           211 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec
             4 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec
           212 page-faults               #    0.000 M/sec
 1,744,441,333 cycles                    #    3.013 GHz                     [20.22%]
 1,064,408,505 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   61.02% frontend cycles idle    [30.68%]
   104,014,063 stalled-cycles-backend    #    5.96% backend  cycles idle    [41.00%]
 2,401,954,846 instructions              #    1.38  insns per cycle
                                         #    0.44  stalled cycles per insn [51.18%]
    14,519,547 branches                  #   25.080 M/sec                   [61.21%]
       109,768 branch-misses             #    0.76% of all branches         [61.48%]
   266,601,318 L1-dcache-loads           #  460.514 M/sec                   [50.90%]
    13,539,746 L1-dcache-load-misses     #    5.08% of all L1-dcache hits   [50.21%]
             0 LLC-loads                 #    0.000 M/sec                   [39.19%]
(wrongevent?)0 LLC-load-misses           #    0.00% of all LL-cache hits    [ 9.63%]

   0.581869522 seconds time elapsed
```

UPDATE Apr 18, 2014

> please explain why cache-references are not correlating with L1-dcache numbers

Cache-references DOES correlate with L1-dcache numbers. `cache-references` is close to `L1-dcache-store-misses` or `L1-dcache-load-misses`. Why numbers are no equal? Because in your CPU (Core i5-2320) there are 3 levels of cache: L1, L2, L3; and LLC (last level cache) is L3. So, load or store instruction at first trys to get/save data in/from L1 cache (`L1-dcache-loads`, `L1-dcache-stores`). If address was not cached in L1, the request will go to L2 (`L1-dcache-load-misses`, `L1-dcache-store-misses`). In this run we have no exact data of how much request were served by L2 (the counters were not included into default set in `perf stat`). But we can assume that some loads/stores were served and some were not. Then not served-by-L2 requests will go to L3 (LLC), and we see that there were 26M references to L3 (`cache-references`) and half of them (13M) were L3 misses (`cache-misses`; served by main RAM memory). Another half were L3 hits.

44M+20M = 64M misses from L1 were passed to L2. 26M requests were passed from L2 to L3 - they are L2 misses. So 64M-26M = 38 millions requests were served by L2 (l2 hits).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer and to add more to my question . Why are the  references not matching with loads and stores

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer and to add more to my question . Why are the  references not matching with loads and stores. to answer your questions . There is no time improvement needed. I just want to understand the tool better. And want to see the 750MB being drawn from the numbers obtained

Comment: krt, can you post your code? What is exact CPU model used by your? How `perf` was started?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char ch, source_file[20], target_file[20];
   FILE *source, *target;
   gets(source_file);
   source = fopen(source_file, "r");
   if( source == NULL )
   {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   gets(target_file);
   target = fopen(target_file, "w");
   if( target == NULL )
   {
      fclose(source);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
 
   while( ( ch = fgetc(source) != EOF ));
      fputc(ch, target);
 
   printf("File copied successfully.\n"); 
   fclose(source);
   fclose(target);
   return 0;
}

Comment: sudo C_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF8 perf stat --log-fd 2  -B -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,L1-dcache-store-misses,cache-references,cache-misses,cycles,instructions ./a.out

Comment: please explain why cache-references are not correlating with L1-dcache numbers.. thanq

Comment: Thank you. Also needed: exact kernel version, glibc version and CPU name. What is exact file size? PS: copying the file byte by byte with "`fgetc`/`fputc`" is the wrong way to measure performance (too much overhead for every byte). Please, use block copy, like 1MB per call.. You can even use zero-copy syscall `sendfile()` - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html

Comment: 3.2.0-60-generic kernel version;;;;;;        
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2320 CPU @ 3.00GHz  ;;;;;;2.15 glibc version         

I'm not concerned with the performance of the code ...  I want to know about the stats given by the perf tool.

Comment: krt, if you want to learn perf and its counters, use more simple examples, without lot of glibc work (check `perf record ./a.out` then `perf report` -- you will see % of time used by `fgetc()` and glibc internals). For example, allocate array in memory, fill it with data, then do N full reads of the array (via pointer), where N is rather high.

Comment: krt, Thank you for all provided details. Check my UPDATE of the answer. If you question is answered, you can "accept" it by clicking `v`-shaped button left to the answer.

Comment: For L1d, each "access" is a single load.  But **L1d only makes one "access" to L2 for multiple loads that miss in the same line**.  The perf events for L2 and L3 cache accesses count only full lines that missed in L1d/L1i, not individual loads.  See this comment on [Throughput analysis on memory copy benchmark](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/95270522) and Hadi's answer.  My math was off by a factor of 64 because I was assuming that LLC-loads was counting mem_inst_retired that missed in L2, but it's not.